# How to use QFileDialog to open virtual folder

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

To choose the folder or file which will be deleted or created on local machine, we can use the class `QFileDialog`.

But my problem is, my folder or file or not exist on local machine, but *on the cloud*. I mean, we can create a HTTP request to get the folder structure from the cloud, but I don't know what is the easiest way to display it on GUI as a `QFileDialog`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl` to select a folder or file from a remote location.

Please note that this is not portable: Qt, when possible, will use the *native* file dialog, which must support selecting remote files to begin with.

The non-native dialog supports only local files, as of version 5.5.

For a portable solution, the only way I see it working is to implement your own, using a `QTreeView`.